How to Use System.Data.IDbCommand's Parameters with SQLite's 'Returning' keyword
I'm trying to add SQLite's RETURNING keyword to an insert query that uses placeholders and is ran via command.ExecuteScalar(). The current query, with the command.Parameters values shown explicitly, looks as such:
INSERT INTO TABLE (column, column, ...)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...)
(value, value, ...)

I've tried appending RETURNING id to the query itself, but then command.executeScalar() runs:
INSERT INTO TABLE (column, column, ...)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...)
RETURNING id
(value, value, ...)

I've tried taking the command, after creation and parameter addition, and using it to make a new command with the appended RETURNING id, but that doesn't bring the parameters with it.
Any help would be much appreciated! :)

what happens with the code as shown? you say it "doesn't bring the parameters with it" - what does that mean? did it return the value? RETURNING provides a grid, so that should be fine with ExecuteScalar() as long as there's a single column and at most one row.

Is there an id column to begin with? You didn't post any C# code so we can't guess how you call these SQL queries. RETURNING returns a result set, not a parameter. ExecuteScalar should work

@MarcGravell with the attempted code shown, a syntax error occurs 'near RETURNING'. by noting that 'it doesn't bring the parameters with it', i've been unable to extract the initial query from the command object successfully (query & parameters)

@PanagiotisKanavos yeah! i've read that 'rowid' is also an alias and i think i got the same behavior there where the hiccup is a syntax error 'near RETURNING' which makes me think it's an order-of-operations problem - RETURNING appearing before the parameters.

@jonathanh the query and parameters are just cmd.CommandText and cmd.Parameters - there shouldn't be any complication there; looking at examples in the docs, I can't see what that last line (value, value, ...) is doing ... maybe just remove that? what is that line trying to do?

@MarcGravell that (value, value, ...) is simply to represent the parameters.

having more eyes on it & the ensuing confusion, i'm getting more worried about the sqlite version rather than the actual code usage. i updated the .dll file, but maybe something could still be referring to a pre-3.35 release

@jonathanh but the (?, ?, ?, ...) already is the parameters...

@MarcGravell sorry, think i mixed up terminology - (?, ?, ...) represents the placeholders / parameters, the (value, value, ...) represents the values in cmd.Parameters / arguments.
judging by your response though, it sounds like i have 'RETURNING id' in the proper place and it should run fine - so, my assumption then is that there's a problem with the sqlite3 version rather than with my implementation.

"(?, ?, ...) represents the placeholders / parameters, the (value, value, ...) represents the values in cmd.Parameters / arguments." - these things are one and the same! Hence my confusion.

@jonathanh ID isn't ROWID. They aren't aliases. The SQLite Auto increment docs say :a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID. It doesn't say "id", it says any integer primary key column is an alias for ROWID. The query itself is wrong and wouldn't have worked even if you tried it with hard-coded values in a SQLite client or IDE like SQLiteStudio. Test your query to ensure it's valid first then try to parameterize it

You shouldn't leave the selection of primary keys to chance either. That's one of the most important design choices in a database. The fact you're trying to return id even though it doesn't exist suggest you haven't specified a primary key at all.
